# How to find and modify a field wherever it is inside document - mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Hi i am trying to find and modify value of a field inside a subcollection of the document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("586d21fd852b50223dc933ab"),
    "book_id" : "JHUE-BOOK-28",
    "Title" : "JJ Boss",
    "published_on" : "21-10-2008",
    "stock_available" : 300,
    "author_address" : [ 
        {
            "perm_address" : "49-44-27/2",
            "perm_city" : null,
            "perm_state" : null,
            "perm_pincode" : null,
            "perm_long" : null,
            "perm_lat" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

I hade a solution to find and modify `stock_available`, `published_on` etc.. with ***fieldname as variable***. but unable to find `perm_city` and soo on inside `author_address` array. i was planning to create one single route to modify individual fields.

> finding field wherever it is inside document

```
router.route('/books/:book_id')
        .post(function(req, res, next){
          var book_id = req.params.book_id;
          var name = req.body.name;
          var value = req.body.value;
          mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
                db.collection('books').update({book_id},{$set:{[name]: value}}, function(err, result){
                  assert.equal(null, err);
                   db.close();
                   res.send('true');
                });
          });
        });
```

The above code is working fine for single field. but not the field inside a array

Comment: Does the `author_address` array always have one element? If not, what is its identifier attribute that is required when updating?

Comment: It is just an example.. This author_address had only on single address element. which holds multiple fields. but i have few more collections which has multiple elements too.. I am trying to find a simple solution to find fieldname as a variable on any level inside collection to edit value.

Comment: The suggested solution is to use the [**`$`** positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in your update but for that to work, the array field must appear as part of the query document.